# Parallel, ordered stringbuilding in Java is being less efficient than sequential implementation

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have an int[][] matrix which updates continually in a while{} loop. After each iteration, I want to print the new values of the matrix to the CLI. I'm writing a parallel version of this loop, so I need to print somehow in parallel. Obviously the order of printing matters... But I'm having issues in testing with the current implementation.It's just too slow and I don't know what to do.

The while loop:

```
int numbOfBlocks = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
int blockSize = matrix.length/numbOfBlocks;
int endRow;

while(true) {
   // print matrix to CLI

   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   CountDownLatch stringBuilderLatch = new CountDownLatch(numbOfBlocks);

   for (int i = 0; i < numbOfBlocks; i++) {
      endRow = (i == numbOfBlocks - 1) ? rows : (i+1) * blockSize;
      StringBuilderThread stringBuilderThread =
            new StringBuilderThread(matrix, i*blockSize, endRow, stringBuilderLatch, stringBuilder, i, numbOfBlocks);
      executor.execute(stringBuilderThread);
   }
   stringBuilderLatch.await();

   stringBuilder.append("___");
   System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

The StringBuilderThread:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class StringBuilderThread implements Runnable {

    private int[][] matrixUpd;
    private int startRow;
    private int endRow;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private StringBuilder mainStringBuilder;
    private int order;
    private int numbOfBlocks;

    public StringBuilderThread(int[][] matrixUpd,
                               int startRow,
                               int endRow,
                               CountDownLatch latch,
                               StringBuilder mainStringBuilder,
                               int order,
                               int numbOfBlocks) {
        this.matrixUpd = matrixUpd;
        this.startRow = startRow;
        this.endRow = endRow;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.mainStringBuilder = mainStringBuilder;
        this.order = order;
        this.numbOfBlocks = numbOfBlocks;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        StringBuilder tempStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int cols = matrixUpd[0].length;
        for (int i = startRow; i < endRow; i++) {
            tempStringBuilder.append("|");
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if(matrixUpd[i][j] == 1) {
                    tempStringBuilder.append("*  ");
                } else {
                    tempStringBuilder.append(".  ");
                }
            }
            tempStringBuilder.append("|\n");
        }
        tempStringBuilder.append(" ");

        // order synchronization, so that threads write to stringbuilders in correct order
        long latchCount = latch.getCount();
        while (!(numbOfBlocks-latchCount == order)) {
            latchCount = latch.getCount();
        }
        mainStringBuilder.append(tempStringBuilder.toString());
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

The issue is, this implementation is actually slower than just printing to CLI sequentially. I suspect the latch is the issue, as multiple threads keep trying to access it, so the threads that actually need it have to wait.

Everything else in my program runs 2x-3x faster in parallel, except this, and it bottlenecking my program.

EDIT:

I tested 3 solutions:

1. Sequential printing
2. Parallel stringbuilding with Callables, then printing the string
3. Parallel stringbuilding with array streams, as suggested by the accepted answer

The results were tested using matrices of dimentions:

1. 200x200, for 100 iterations
2. 1000x1000, for 100 iterations
3. 2000x2000, for 200 iterations
4. 4000x4000, for 200 iterations

Array parallel streams had the best performance in every test and were the simplest to implement.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "It's just too slow and I don't know what to do" just do it in a single thread.

Comment: The point of my implementation is to showcase efficiency increases in parallel processing. I'm sure this can be made faster than sequential processing, i'm just stuck in the implementation, and im missing the mistake.

Comment: Why would you implement converting the matrix to a String in a Thread?

Comment: "to showcase efficiency increases in parallel processing" perhaps this shows that such a conclusion is incorrect?

Comment: Why not? I can split the matrix into blocks, each can be converted to a string in parallel, i can get the string faster.

Comment: @AndyTurner either you're correct or my implementation has a mistake :) im not sure which

Comment: "Why not" is a silly answer, because, as you saw yourself, it does not get faster.

Comment: I understand it's not faster, i'm just not sure if that is because it cannot be made faster, or i am making a mistake in the logic of the code, hence me coming here to ask.

Comment: Did you measure where, in the single threaded version, the cpu / io / memory bottleneck is? You can't make something faster if you don't understand what it is that makes it 'slow'

Comment: @AnonymousStudent "*i'm just not sure if that is because it cannot be made faster or...*" You literally said before "*I'm sure this can be made faster*".

Comment: All of this latching stuff seems wildly complicated. _Assuming some threading is needed_, I would just use an `ExecutorService`, create a bunch of `Callable<String>`s and submit, wait for all of them all to be done, then concatenate. But it seems like a totally trivial thing that is best done in a single thread, and multithreading is just sledgehammer/walnut.

Comment: As Andy already suggested you could try to do the concatenation in the end, especially since order matters. That means you shouldn't have all threads wait until it's their turn but rather return the blocks along with their index and concatenate them in the main thread. This is very similar to having an ordered collector on a parallel stream instead of trying to have a synchronized reduce operation, in fact you could try to express your operation that way.

Comment: One more thing on your tests: at a certain point printing to the console might outweigh the conversion code so no matter your approach you might not be seeing much difference. On the other hand, smaller matrices would lead to less room for optimization so less difference there as well (or as was commented thread overhead might even worsen it). So try to do the comparisons without the printing.

Comment: The comparisons without the printing are much improved with parallel implementation. However, i found that concatinating a string and than printing only that is faster than continually printing, hence ,im just trying to improve the concatenation as much as possible now. I will try both the callable method and the answer by alex r and get back with the results.

Comment: Polling `getCount()` is perverting the purpose of a `CountDownLatch`. Note further that `mainStringBuilder.append(tempStringBuilder.toString());` copies the entire builder contents into a new `String` before appending it to the target builder, copying the contents again doubling the work. Use `mainStringBuilder.append(tempStringBuilder);` instead, without `.toString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't expect to see a performance increase for small matrices. There is some overhead involved by using threads and you should have some proper benchmarks to measure any performance changes.

In any case, if you want to try parallelizing your operations, you can try out parallel streams to map your `int[]` rows to strings. According to the [package summary](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and the specification of [Stream#collect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) that should not change the result as the Collector returned by `Collectors.joining` is not concurrent.

> Except for operations identified as explicitly nondeterministic, such as findAny(), whether a stream executes sequentially or in parallel should not change the result of the computation.

> If the stream is parallel, and the Collector is concurrent, and either the stream is unordered or the collector is unordered, then a concurrent reduction will be performed (see Collector for details on concurrent reduction.)

```java
final int[][] matrix = {
        {1, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1}
};

String collect = Arrays.stream(matrix).parallel()
        .map(ints -> Arrays.stream(ints)
                .mapToObj(value -> value == 1 ? "*" : ".")
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" ", "|", "|"))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
System.out.println(collect);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
|* . * .|
|. . . *|
```

Comment: @AnonymousStudent No, it uses `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` which has by default `#cores - 1` threads available. You can also print the current thread from within the first `map` operation using `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());`. For big matrices you should see different threads being used.

Comment: Given 4 cores, would it not be more efficient to compute the strings with 4 blocks of the matrix(eg, if a matrix has 8000 rows, each core gets 2000), rather than the threads continually processing the rows one by one? In other words, is there no overhead to minimized task "size"? Pardon the ignorance of the question, I'm just trying to get a grasp of how parallel processing should be approached.

Comment: @AnonymousStudent You should be careful with such assumptions even if they seem logical to you. One way to test your assumptions is to compare multiple implementations with each other through benchmarks (e.g [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh)). But even benchmarks might fail you and what runs faster on one machine might be slower on a different one. In my opinion, you should stick with the simplest solution that is "fast enough".

Comment: @AnonymousStudent there is no sense in first assuming a particular, inefficient implementation strategy, followed by criticizing that implementation strategy. The stream API is *not* processing rows “one by one” when parallel processing is enabled. It *is* implemented by subdividing the range of elements (here: rows) into halves until all cores have equal workloads (assuming that the even subdivision is possible, which is always the case for `Arrays.stream(…)`).